# Adding a generic object to a Dictionary<string, T> in C# - Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, dictionary

I am getting a Null Reference Exception, but can't figure out why (see code).

I have the following code as part of a deserializer I'm making. The following code adds the default key/values to a set of dictionaries when the deserialised instance of my class is missing some keys. The reason for this is so that when a customer deploys a new version of my plugin, their old settings will still deserilize properly, even if they don't have all the keys.

Here's my code:

```
private Dictionary<string, T> AddMissingSettings<T>(Dictionary<string, T> settingsObject, bool forceDefaults, string[] settingsList)
{
    if (forceDefaults || settingsObject == null)
    {
        settingsObject = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    }
    foreach (string t in settingsList)
    {
        if (!settingsObject.ContainsKey(t))
        {
            settingsObject.Add(t, default(T));// Null Reference Exception Here
        }
    }
    return settingsObject;
}
```

Here is an example of me envoking the method:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> Times = getlistoftimesettingsfromdata();
//Note: Not the real way Times gets set, but whatever
Times = AddMissingSettings<DateTime>(Times, forceDefaults, new string[] { "LastEmailUpdate", "IdealRegularReportTime", "LastRegularReport" });
//Also, pretty sure the "Times = " here is redundant, but let it pass
```

EDIT
VPNd into work to post the actual code I'm using. I can confirm that it compiles and runs.

```
    private void LoadDefaults(bool forceDefaults)
    {
        if (RegularReportDays == null || forceDefaults) { RegularReportDays = new List<DayOfWeek>(); }
        if (RegularReportSubscribers == null || forceDefaults) { RegularReportSubscribers = new List<string>(); }
        Times = AddMissingSettings<DateTime>(Times, forceDefaults, DateTime.MinValue, new string[] { "LastEmailUpdate", "IdealRegularReportTime", "LastRegularReport" });
        Toggles = AddMissingSettings<bool>(Toggles, forceDefaults, false, new string[] { "AutomaticUpdates", "AutomaticUpdatesAlerts", "SendRegularReports" });
    }

    private Dictionary<string, T> AddMissingSettings<T>(Dictionary<string, T> settingsObject, bool forceDefaults, T defaultValue, string[] settingsList)
    {
        if (forceDefaults || settingsObject == null)
        {
            settingsObject = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        }
        foreach (string t in settingsList)
        {
            if (!settingsObject.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                settingsObject.Add(t, defaultValue);
            }
        }
        return settingsObject;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If `settingsObject` were `null` the `if` would have thrown earlier. Are you triple sure?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a `NullReferenceException`? I think you are getting an `ArgumentNullException` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you critiquing my coding-style? If so, thanks for the input, but that wasn't actually my problem. Incidentally, settingsObject can be null, and if it is, then we want to set the default `Dictionary<string, T>`

Comment: `"Times = " here is redundant` depends on `forceDefaults`, so assume: No. Keep it in.

Comment: is settingsObject null when you get exception?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's `settingsObject.Add(t, default(T));// Null Reference Exception Here`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, no sure it's Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @IainFraser: With the code you have shown us, this is ***impossible***. Please show us the code you really use.

Comment: Are you sure your code was compiled as you're showing it?...ie did you try a rebuild?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I'm sure there's something I'm missing - it was Friday afternoon when I posted this and I was/am pretty burnt out. Pretty sure it compiled okay, but I'll check on Monday. Also, I will double check my code sample - I did strip out some diagnostic stuff I was doing before posting it - to avoid confusion, maybe I stripped out or left in something extra in my haste.

Comment: @kirrill not at my comp just now, but seem to remember seeing .Count == 0 in Quickwatch, so it wouldn't have been null.

Comment: Added real code. Please note I'm explicitly passing the default value here as an argument as a diagnostic - this doesn't work either :/. Thanks for the help so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've come back fresh and bright on Monday and I see what the issue is. The problem was happening - as others have sniffed out - further up the stack. The key to this solution is in a place I didn't mention because I didn't think it was relevant (sorry).

I was trying to run the following stack

- `private Dictionary<string, T> AddMissingSettings<T>(Dictionary<string, T> settingsObject, bool forceDefaults, string[] settingsList)`
- `private void LoadDefaults(bool forceDefaults)`
- `public BookEasyImportServiceSettings(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext cxt)`

You might notice that I'm trying to alter the members of an object, whilst it is being deserialized. It seems you can't do that. So I added a public `LoadMissingDefaults` method to my interface and I call it when the `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream)` has finished.

Now, I really don't like awarding answers to myself (although equally, I don't like solving my problem and not sharing my solution - so I do it sometimes). If anyone can submit a good answer as to why this is the case and/or a better way of doing it, I'll switch the awarded answer to them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `null` as a key in `Dictionary`. From your code `settingsList` is `string[]` and `string` can be `null`. I would suggest you to check null before you add it to `settingObject`.

```
foreach (string t in settingsList) 
{ 
    if (t != null && !settingsObject.ContainsKey(t)) 
    { 
        settingsObject.Add(t, default(T));// Null Reference Exception Here 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's what my comment pointed to. But a null as key yields an `ArgumentNullException`, not a `NullReferenceException`.